# Accessing an outside variable inside a javascript event

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm building a server which acts as a proxy between a browser and a third party service using websockets. the general sequence is

1. Browser connects to server via websocket
2. After authentication , the server connects via websocket to a third party service.
3. the third party service sends a message to the server which relays it back to the browser

One problem i'm trying to solve is to disconnect the websocket from server -> third party service whenever the socket from the browser disconnects.

To that extent, i'm thinking of maintaining an object like the below

```
var thirdPartySockets = {};
```

whenever a client socket connects :

```
var ServerSocket = connectToThirdParty (clientSocketId, URL);
thirdPartySockets [clientSocketId] = ServerSocket;
```

The code for connectToThirdParty

```
var connectToThirdParty = function(clientSocketId, URL){

    var client = new WebSocketClient();

    client.on('connectFailed', function(err) {
        console.log('connection failed')
    });

    client.on('connect', function(connection) {

        connection.on('error', function(err) {

        });

        connection.on('close', function() {
           // attempt reconnection
        });

        connection.on('message', function(message) {   
            // send back to client
        });

    });

    client.connect(URL);
    return client
}
```

The problem here is i'm trying to disconnect the server socket whenever the browser socket disconnects. I cannot seem to access the thirdPartySocket list object in the `disconnect` event.

```
var thirdPartySockets = {};

 io.on('connection', function(socket){

        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
           // how do i access the thidPartySockets object here?
        });
    });
```

Are there better ways to handle this situation?

Comment: I don't think there's a better option.

Comment: whats wrong with custom object?

Comment: @wrangler - sorry i dont understand